# Two column? list with arrows between items

Tags: lists, arrows

How would one achieve a list of two columns like this one:

[image]

I only want list bullets on the left side, so in fact if each entry is a single item that's fine. Items never span multiple lines. I've tried using an align block and two-column lists, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeX provides a `\rightarrowfill` command that does just this.  It's a standard part of plain TeX and LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\abox}[2]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2 \rightarrowfill}}    
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \abox{1in}{Item 1} Explanation 1
    \item \abox{1in}{Item 2} Explanation 2
    \item \abox{1in}{Item 3} Explanation 3
    \item \abox{1in}{Last item} Last explanation
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want "nicer" arrows, just add `\usepackage{mathabx}` or otherwise redefine `\rightarrow` to your favourite arrow symbol.  This works because `\rightarrrowfill` uses the current definition of `\rightarrow`.

There's also a corresponding `\leftarrowfill` command.

You can define the command using plain TeX facilities as well, if you wanted to use it without LaTeX:

```
\def\abox#1#2{\leavevmode\hbox to #1{#2\ \rightarrowfill}}
```

An alternative approach, that might work better if you have long explanations, would be to make a new list environment that used `\rightarrowfill`.  For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{calc} % needed to use + in \setlength
\newenvironment{arrowlist}[1][1in]%
 {\begin{list}{}{%
   \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\indent\textbullet\ \textit{##1}\ \rightarrowfill}%
   \setlength{\labelwidth}{#1}%
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
   }}
{\end{list}}
\begin{document}

\begin{arrowlist}
  \item[First thing] Explanation 1 
  \item[Second one] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
    Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{arrowlist}

Or to make the labels longer than 1in...

\begin{arrowlist}[1.4in]
  \item[First thing] Explanation 1 
  \item[Second one] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
     Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\end{arrowlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rightarrowfill` is available also in standard LaTeX; instead of primitive commands, `\newcommand{\abox}[2]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2 \rightarrowfill}}` should be used.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I'll update the answer, `def` and `hbox` always come more quickly to my fingers...

Answer (score 4):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength\BoxWd
\newlength\TextWd
\newlength\ArrowWd
\setlength\BoxWd{9em}
\newcommand\MyItem[2]{%
  \settowidth\TextWd{#1}%
  \setlength\ArrowWd{\dimexpr\BoxWd-\TextWd\relax}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\BoxWd+1em\relax][l]{%
    #1$\xrightarrow{\hspace*{\ArrowWd}}$%
  }\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\BoxWd-1em\relax}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item\MyItem{Some text.}{A little description.}
\item\MyItem{Some other text.}{A little description.}
\item\MyItem{Text.}{A longer description. The text now will span more than one line. In fact, it will span three lines just for the example.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax is:

```
\MyItem{<item>}{<explanation>}
```

Control the width using the `\BoxWd` length.

Answer (score 3):

I imported a stealth arrow head from `mathabx` because I thought it looked better than the computer modern version.  The parameters `\def\arrowlength{3cm}` and `\def\bulletskip{0.5cm}` may be reset to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\arrowlength{3cm}
\def\bulletskip{0.5cm}
\def\rarrow#1{\mathrel{\rule[2.15pt]{#1}{0.7pt}\kern-2.5ex\varrightarrow}}
\def\aritem#1#2{\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}\setstackgap{L}{0pt}%
  \noindent$\bullet$\hspace{\bulletskip}%
  \stackon{$\rarrow{\arrowlength}$}{\colorbox{white}{#1}}~\textit{#2}}

\begin{document}

\aritem{Item 1}{Explanation 1}\\
\aritem{Item 2}{Explanation 2}\\
\aritem{Item 3}{Explanation 3}\\
\aritem{Last Item}{Last Explanation}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]